# Study about beliefs overriding drug effect

Tags: drug-tolerance, placebo

Now placebo is one thing that is documented and proven.

However, I came across the following which claims that our beliefs can override drug effect:

> One researcher in this field, Dr. Henry Beecher from Harvard University, explained through some of his experiments that the success we commonly attribute to a medication’s impact on a condition might actually be the patient's belief that this truly is the magic potion. Let’s look at 2 examples:
>
> One of the most widely known examples of this concept, put into experimental practice, involved 100 medical students who were recruited to test 2 new medications: a “super stimulant” red capsule, and a “super tranquilizer” blue capsule.2 This was what they were told they were given, but in reality the 2 were intentionally switched, that is, the red capsule was actually the tranquilizer (a barbiturate), and the blue capsule contained the stimulant (an amphetamine).
>
> The results of what the participants experienced was striking: They were right in line with the subject’s expectations. The subjects were told that they received a stimulant but it was really a tranquilizer, and felt they stimulated. Meanwhile, those who were told that they would be taking a tranquilizer but actually were given a stimulant felt tired. Taking this yet a step further really drives the power of beliefs home: These students were not given placebos; they got the actual medications.

Source: [website](https://www.pharmacytimes.com/contributor/adam-martin-pharmd-acsm-cpt/2018/02/the-power-of-the-placebo-effect)

I am having trouble finding the actual study to at least see be able to see the Amphetamine dosage that was used in this study.

The study referenced on the linked site is:

> 2. Blackwell B, Bloomfield SS, Buncher CR. Demonstration to medical students of placebo responses and non-drug factors. Lancet. 1972;1(7763):1279-82.

Does anyone know where to dig up this study?

Comment: Here's a short abstract, not very useful: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0140673672909968?via%3Dihub and if you insist, you may want to try and contact them: https://s100.copyright.com/AppDispatchServlet?publisherName=ELS&contentID=S0140673672909968&orderBeanReset=true

Comment: Thank you! The name of the study matches and even in abstract it states:  "The subjects were conditioned to expect sedative or stimulant effects, but ALL received PLACEBO in one or two blue or pink capsules". Hence, thus far it looks like it's a case of 'Chinese whisperers' game and the participants were actually given a placebo not reverse drug.